# Low GUI performance of some apps running in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wslg

I have very low GUI performance of certain apps running in WSL (specifically Google Chrome and IntelliJ IDEA). It feels like there's no hardware acceleration. GUI windows are very unresponsive (key presses and scrolling have very noticeable lag), there's no smoothness and interactions cause high CPU load.

I have noticed this chopiness after changing my monitor from a 1080p to a 4K one.

What is interesting is that some apps are fine (e.g., gedit is smooth even though it takes ~30s to start).

glxgears gives me ~130fps which is ridiculously low (on a 1660 Ti).

I am running Arch Linux, up to date, systemd enabled.

What could be causing the slowness of Chrome and IDEA (and glxgears)? Anything I could check to help me diagnose the problem?

Below is the output of glxinfo which may be useful (I don't see anything wrong):

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_ATI_pixel_format_float, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Microsoft Corporation (0xffffffff)
    Device: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 23.1.4
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 22327MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.2
    Max compat profile version: 4.2
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.1.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect,
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_texture_texture4,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clip_control,
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted,
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output,
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_direct_state_access,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect,
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location,
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions,
    GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, GL_ARB_fragment_shader,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64,
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_indirect_parameters,
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
    GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_program_interface_query,
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters,
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters,
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size,
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine,
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing,
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_float,
    GL_ARB_texture_gather, GL_ARB_texture_multisample,
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels,
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg,
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample,
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit,
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev,
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array,
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_texture_float,
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync, GL_EXT_abgr,
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2,
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_memory_object,
    GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float,
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_semaphore,
    GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_texture_array,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback,
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit,
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile,
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_pack_invert,
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba,
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, GL_OES_EGL_image,
    GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 4.2 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.1.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels,
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clip_control,
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted,
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output,
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image,
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64,
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex,
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2,
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect,
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query,
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile,
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_ARB_robustness,
    GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map,
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops,
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding,
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size, GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine,
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_include,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing,
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_float,
    GL_ARB_texture_gather, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod,
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui,
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle,
    GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_separate_stencil,
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float,
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra,
    GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_debug_label,
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_memory_object,
    GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels,
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
    GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side,
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map,
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer,
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback,
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit,
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip,
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error,
    GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
    GL_KHR_robustness, GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_pack_invert,
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba,
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility, GL_NV_blend_square,
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image,
    GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_half_float,
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection,
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vdpau_interop,
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc,
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 23.1.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_pack_reverse_row_order, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_texture_max_level,
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_base_instance,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_buffer_storage,
    GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_color_buffer_float,
    GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture, GL_EXT_debug_label,
    GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer,
    GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers,
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_float_blend, GL_EXT_frag_depth,
    GL_EXT_geometry_point_size, GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5,
    GL_EXT_instanced_arrays, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, GL_EXT_memory_object,
    GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean, GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box,
    GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness,
    GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd,
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions,
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks,
    GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size, GL_EXT_tessellation_shader,
    GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_buffer,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
    GL_EXT_texture_norm16, GL_EXT_texture_query_lod, GL_EXT_texture_rg,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV,
    GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile,
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_bgra,
    GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions,
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments,
    GL_NV_generate_mipmap_sRGB, GL_NV_image_formats, GL_NV_pack_subimage,
    GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_NV_read_depth,
    GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil,
    GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation, GL_OES_EGL_image,
    GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3,
    GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_depth24,
    GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map,
    GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
    GL_OES_geometry_point_size, GL_OES_geometry_shader,
    GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_gpu_shader5, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box,
    GL_OES_required_internalformat, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading,
    GL_OES_sample_variables, GL_OES_shader_image_atomic,
    GL_OES_shader_io_blocks, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation,
    GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil8, GL_OES_surfaceless_context,
    GL_OES_tessellation_point_size, GL_OES_tessellation_shader,
    GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_border_clamp, GL_OES_texture_buffer,
    GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array, GL_OES_texture_float,
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float,
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot,
    GL_OES_texture_stencil8, GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array,
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float,
    GL_OES_viewport_array
```

Comment: It could be anything that you have installed.